A property about points not in any facet of a convex hull
I am trying to make sense of a certain lemma in this article, lemma 2. I think there's a mistake in the statement. I am new to convex geometry, so a simple yes or no to my question would help me a lot and point me in the right direction.
Let $$\Omega=conv(v_1,\cdots,v_n)=\{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\lambda_i v_i : \sum_{k=1}^{n}\lambda_i=1 \text{ and }\lambda_i\geq0 \}$$ and $x\in\Omega$ not in any facet of $\Omega$.
Can we find $y_1\cdots y_m$ all in $\Omega$ linearally independent, and $\beta_1\cdots \beta_m$ all $>0$ with $\sum_{k=1}^{m}\beta_i=1$ such that  $x=\sum_{k=1}^{m}\beta_i y_i$?
My attempt
Because a facet of $\Omega$ is $\Omega_i=conv(v_1\cdots \hat v_{i}\cdots v_n)$ (the hat is for omitting), and since $x$ is convex combination of the $v_i$'s; $x$ not in any facet, the scalars in that convex combination must be all non zero. that is $$x=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\beta_k v_k$$ where all $\beta_i>0$. but how about the linear independency?

MSE is not a "do my homework/work for me" site. Posts like this (e.g. "PSQs") are in poor taste, & often downvoted & closed; we expect users to put in effort! If you want meaningful help, [edit] your post to add relevant context (more), e.g. relevant definitions, your work/attempts, the problem's source, where specifically you're stuck, what you do/don't understand & have learned recently, & so on. If needed: this is useful for formatting LaTeX, & Approach0 helps find past questions.
